# Excel chart - how to hide blank series?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-charts

My application generates a report based on the template. In that application user can define Years range (column A). And application dynamically will add new rows.

This report has also Chart, and because of the dynamic row count I had to add selection for multiple rows. Everything works fine except one thing. Blank rows (series), are displayed on that chart's legend and bars have less space because of these empty bars. Is there any way to not displaying chart for blank series?

I was trying to use some macros, formulas etc. but without any success.
[Here is the link to the excel file](https://products.aspose.app/cells/editor/edit?FolderName=d1c441b2-2d2b-4997-b84b-fa3030b1727f&FileName=report.xlsx&Uid=4e084959-bbfd-420e-9b3f-b832fe432bc9.xlsx)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform your range into a table and restrict the chart to the table rows.
If you add new data to the table, the table will extend automatically, and the chart will follow. There is no need to add extra rows in the chart for the years to come.

I am sorry for your lost time.

Is this solution acceptable?

1. Small table
   [image]
2. Bigger table (the year has a formula to autofill). Dragging the corners of the table, the chart updates.

[image]

You can download the file from here:
https://link.nithins.me/zV0is0Ub

Steps:

1. In the column Year put characters, not numbers
2. Select any cell in the range (or table) and insert a chart. Because the first column is text, the chart recognizes it as label series.
3. Switch Row/Column in the chart's property.
4. Put back the years as they were before. If you have a table and you write a formula like `=2020+ROW()-ROW(A$1)`, then as you add a new row, it will calculate the new year.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Can you edit spreadsheet and upload? I don't think I follow. Because chart can be defined for the exact rows/cells range. How am I suppose to set range to the entire table?

Comment: I am sorry, it was late in the night. I think that this link explains better what I wanted to say: https://www.officetooltips.com/excel_365/tips/creating_automatically_extended_plot_ranges.html

Comment: I spent over the 1h trying to apply this on my raport and I can't :/ Because I have multiple columns, and on that example there is only one column.

Comment: It's definately better. Thanks! Although still I need to drag the corner. Is there any chance to avoid that? With macro or so? Because currently by default it generates chart for first row only. 
https://prnt.sc/q4quhfVDPUmS

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong. If you click once on my chart, you can see that the entire table is selected. https://prnt.sc/llVmFFIf921I

Comment: Upload the Excel file again, and I will fix it for you. That would be faster. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: https://easyupload.io/22c6ex Here is my report. My .NET application added new rows, but when I open the report - chart is only for the first row, and I need to extand it manually. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think the problem is in your .NET application: you are deleting the rows and recreating them. Have you tried writing over the existing values? I made several modifications: 1. the year is calculated thru formula, do not use your application to rewrite it. 2. the 0 values are present, but now shown so it will be easier to spot the real numbers. Anyway, see here your file: https://easyupload.io/240doi

Comment: Yea I think when workbook is updated by .net then formulas are not refreshed. That's why I have to drag this corner. Anyway it's still better than before. If you can then update your answer with more details (which formula you used etc., might be helpful for other people).